# Query with three tables, no common column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, join

I've just started a job and my boss wants me to learn mySQL so please bear with me, i've been learning for only 2 days and i'm not that good at it yet.

So i've been given 3 tables and several tasks to do.

The tables are:

1. mobile_log_messages_sms
2. mobile_providers
3. service_instances

And in them i've got to:

- Find out how many messages there were in the last 25 days and how
  much income did they make
- Then i need to group them by day (so per day, exclude hours) and
  provider name.
- Also i need to ignore all the messages that have an empty string
  under the service column
- Also i need to ignore the messages that made 0 income and count only
  those that have the column service_enabled = 1
- And then i need to sort it descending, by date.

in the tables 
**mobile_log_messages_sms**:

- message_id - used to count the messages
- price - using for price obviously, exlude those with 0
- time - date in yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss format
- service - exclude all those that have an empty string (or null)

**mobile_providers**

- provider_name - to use to group with

**service_instances**

- enabled - only use if value is 1

I've started with:

```
SELECT message_id, price, time
FROM mobile_log_messages_sms
WHERE time BETWEEN '2017-02-26 00:00:00'
AND time AND '2017-03-22 00:00:00'
```

But i need to change the date format and then use the JOIN commands but i don't know how, and i know i need to add more to it, but i'm stumped even at the start. Also the starting just lists the messages but i need to count the total sum of the income (price) per day.

Can anyone point me in the right direction at least since i'm still a noob? Many thanks in advance and sorry if i worded something badly, english is not my first language.

Comment: `WHERE time BETWEEN '2017-02-26 00:00:00' AND time AND '2017-03-22 00:00:00'` should be `WHERE time BETWEEN '2017-02-26 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-22 00:00:00'`

Comment: you don't need to use `JOIN` to do this, simply do `FROM mobile_log_messages_sms log, mobile_providers prov,  service_instances si`

Comment: @Vivick those are joins...cross joins to be precise. And they have been out of favor for 25 years now with that syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: still does the job well :3. Don't wanna go around and talk about right outer joins or others for days so I use the easiest one to understand (being the Cartesian Product).

Comment: implicit joins are bad mmmmkay

Answer (score 0):

Find out how many messages there were in the last 25 days and how much income did they make

**1.**

```
SELECT COUNT(message_id), SUM(price)
FROM mobile_log_messages_sms
WHERE CAST(time AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 25 DAY) 
AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

**2.**

```
SELECT COUNT(message_id), SUM(price)
FROM mobile_log_messages_sms
WHERE CAST(time AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 25 DAY) 
AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY CAST(time AS DATE);
```

**3.**

```
SELECT COUNT(message_id), SUM(price)
FROM mobile_log_messages_sms
WHERE CAST(time AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 25 DAY) 
AND CURRENT_DATE AND service IS NULL
GROUP BY CAST(time AS DATE);
```

rest can't done with join so make sure that at least one column should be common in tables.

Comment: and what if i want to make it between 2017-02-26 00:00:00 and 2017-03-22 00:00:00 but without the time, as in: i want it to count the messages recieved per day, ignoring the hh:mm:ss